# A/B testing of newsletter in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, statistical-significance

I have conducted A/B test on Newsletter send outs regarding title length over 10 week period. One group of people during those weeks always got long title, other short version of title. Newsletters did not differ in other things then title, content was same.

To check if in one particular case one of the newsletter in pair had higher Open Ratio I need to use test of proportions (`t.test`). The better result in one particular case might be due to better title text, not due to length of title, but other factors (for example more funny or more elegant: Short - "Buy with us", Long - "Need present for Christmas? Buy with us"). So how can I take into account repetitiveness of the test and check if one option was systematically better Open Rate then other?

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)

NL_Data <- data.frame(Title= rep(c("Short", "Long"), 10),
                  Date = rep(as.Date("2017-01-01") + 7*1:10 , each = 2),
                  Open_Rate = c(runif(10, min = 0.02, max = 0.04), runif(10, min = 0.03, max = 0.05)),
                  Sample_Size = rep(c(350000, 500000), 10))
```

My idea is to calculate mean Open_Rate in each type of newsletter (with Long and Short title) and then do a t.test with sample size equal to sum of each send-out.

Comment: 10 weeks isn't very long, but you should try a paired t-test. It is an option in the t.test function of r.

Comment: `t.test` is not test of proportions, but test of means. What you need to use is `prop.test`. The ideal dataset of an AB test like that, when your target metric is Open Rate, should have been coded as 1 if emailed was opened (at least once) and coded as 0 if email was not opened. Open Ratio is a different thing and it's not a proportion even if it looks like one, If you send out 1 email and the user opens it twice then the open ratio is 2 and by default not a proportion.

Comment: Also, why did you stop the test after 10 weeks? Did you do any analysis in advance to prove that this time frame is enough to spot statistically significant differences in your target metric?

Comment: Some info here might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361942/ab-testing-analysis-in-r-prop-test-or-t-test , http://www.emailmarketingtipps.de/2012/05/14/sample-sizes-in-email-split-testing/ , http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/ab-testing-explained-challenged-digital-marketing-case-study-example-part-2/

Comment: @JonnoBourne - I selected 10 weeks period as we would like to test many things, and 10 newsletters seemed like pretty fair time frame to test. How many newsletters do you recommend?

Comment: @AntoniosK - The Open Rate I have already takes into account the problem you mentioned, and is counting if a person opened a mail at least once. 
I did not do any analysis a propri. How should I approach it? Thanks! I will read those pages

Answer (score 0):

I propose to go away from the t-test and to the test of proportions given by `prop.test`. You need absolute numbers instead of shares for that:

```
NL_Data$Open <- round(NL_Data$Open_Rate*NL_Data$Sample_Size) #compute absolute numbers of opened emails

opened <- tapply(NL_Data$Open, NL_Data$Title, sum)  # total in all samples
sampled <- tapply(NL_Data$Sample_Size, NL_Data$Title, sum) # total in all samples
prop.test(opened, sampled) # test it via chi squared
```